# Can I commit initial untracked files in git using this command "git commit -am"?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, gitlab

I want to commit the first files of my project. They are the very first files immidiately after I initialize the project's folder to bring Git into play in that folder. I wanted to use the command "git commit -am" (with the -a option) to both track these files, and create a commit for that, while skipping the "git add" stage. But git returns the files [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPaGz.png)to me saying they are untrackked files, which I know and ofcourse I think what I am doing is to track them.

Comment: Do you have a `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Short answer: "no". See [YoshiMbele's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72443872/1256452) as well, but I recommend *avoiding* `git commit -a` as a habit. It will cause you grief in the long run. Use `git status`, `git add`, and `git diff --cached` to review commits before running `git commit`. (I also recommend minimizing the use of `-m` when committing because it prevents you from writing a good commit message, but that's another topic entirely.)

Comment: Please clarify for me @torek, how will 'git commit -a' cause me more grief in the long run. And also why does '-m' prevent me from writing good commit messages? What is the better option I should use. Kindly enlighten me.

Comment: If you get used to using `git commit -a`, you will eventually forget to `git add` some file. (I've done it myself and seen it many times from other Git newbies. It isn't *guaranteed* to bite *everyone* but it sure seems common.) As for `-m`, the problem here is that you're usually limited in size. Take a look at [this Git commit message](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0353c6881890db1302f0f1bdf85c6076eed61113) and imagine typing all that in with `-m`.

Comment: I get you. What can I use in place of -m when I want to write long commit messages?

Comment: Usually one should refrain from writing long commit messages. Commits are supposed to be small changes in your code base, therefore the messages going with them can be short and concise as well. Commit often, they are free after all and you gain a lot more points in your code history to roll back to.

Answer (score 4):

If you check the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt--a) for the "git commit" command, it explicitly states, that it will:

> automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.

Therefore the command does not work the way you expect it to. You have to `git add .` new and untracked files first.